# Importing another project as modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Suppose I have a project in the following structure

```
projectfoo/
|- mymodule/
|--|- __init__.py
|--|- library.py
|- preprocessor.py
```

and in the `__init__.py` in `mymodule` looks like this

```
from . import library #library itself has other functions

def some_function():
    blar blar blar...
```

and the `preprocessor.py` would look like follows

```
import mymodule

def main():
    something()

def something():
    mymodule.some_function() # calls the function defined in __init__.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I started `projectbar`, which is using a lot of common code from `projectfoo`. So instead of copying and pasting code between projects, I wish to import `projectfoo` into project bar, as follows.

```
projectbar/
|- projectfoo/
|--|- mymodule/
|--|--|- __init__.py
|--|--|- library.py
|--|- preprocessor.py
|- index.py
```

So I am trying to import `preprocessor` in my `index.py` as follows

```
from projectfoo import preprocessor
```

However I am getting an error saying `preprocessor.py` is now unable to import `mymodule`.

```
ImportError: No module named 'mymodule'
```

Am I doing this correctly? I am using python3.4 running in ubuntu 14.04 in my setup.

EDIT: I also tried adding `__init__.py` to `projectfoo`, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Modifying the PYTHONPATH environment variable may help. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you did not added the path of **preprocessor**  as a library package

```
from sys import path as pylib #im naming it as pylib so that we won't get confused between os.path and sys.path 
import os
pylib += [os.path.abspath(r'/projectfoo')]
from projectfoo import preprocessor
```

FYI: os.path will return the absolute path. but sys.path will return the path env. variable in system settings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works, but is it possible to not having to import `sys` and `os` whenever I need to import anything from `projectfoo`? I mean can I have those lines executed for all scripts in `projectbar` automatically?

Comment: to my knowledge this is the best possible way. You can skip importing OS, if you can specify the absolute path, like for instance 'd:\files\python\projectfoo' . I am not telling it's not possible, but to my knowledge this is the best way how i can do it. :)

Comment: erm, I actually wanted to ask whether i can run the os and sys import somewhere automatically, so that I don't have to copy and paste the same lines in multiple scripts in `projectbar`

Comment: According to what i feel, you will not be running all the scripts manually, You will have only one main script that will be executed by you(this is a guess,coz, dats how i do it.) you can add these two lines in that one script . :)

Comment: @san One small query. Doesn't it look for projectfoo inside the current directory?

Comment: I am not sure of it @MukundGandlur , as far as i know i think it will look in the current directory not in it's child directories.

Comment: @san unfortunately i am writing multiple scripts and each of them are to be executed manually lol, i guess i will figure out a way then

Comment: @Jeffrey04 i wish you will get one buddy :) . Happy Coding :)

Comment: If you are on a Linux/Unix-like system & running the scripts for the shell, all you need to do is to add the `projectbar` directory to your `$PYTHONPATH`, in you `.bashrc`/`.zshenv` (depending on you shell) : `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/projectbar:$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: nah, I put those lines into `projectfoo`'s `__init__.py` problem solved

Comment: @Jeffrey04  Those lines in the sense? May I know what to add?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add empty `__init__.py` to `projectfoo` folder.

Comment: argh, i forgot to say, i tried with and without __init__.py, wouldn't work, same problem

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an `__init__.py` file (can be empty) in your `projectfoo/` folder to make it a valid module.

Then use relative imports to explicitly specify you're requesting the current module's submodule `mymodule` like this:

```
from .projectfoo import preprocessor
```

The `.` stands for the current module in which the file containing the import statement is located. Its parent module would be denoted as `..`, its "grandparent" would be `...` etc.

Comment: argh, i forgot to say, i tried with and without `__init__.py`, wouldn't work, same problem

Comment: @Jeffrey04 Keep the `__init__.py` in place and change your import line to a relative import: `from .projectfoo import preprocessor` (note the dot before `projectfoo` which stands for the current module) Does this work?

Comment: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` LOL

Comment: @Jeffrey04 Then probably you have to add another `__init__.py` in your `projectbar` directory, I guess.

Comment: tried, still same error (: check the accepted answer for solution lol

Comment: @Jeffrey04 And if you use the import line `from projectbar.projectfoo import preprocessor` instead? I did similar stuff some months ago and it *did* work without manipulating the PATH (which I personally would see as bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to keep your file as a module and use 'sys' to import it as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/absolute/path/to/the/other/project")

import your_module
```

Another approach is to make it a package and install it.

1. **Structure your project as a package**: Make sure your project has the following structure:

```
my_project/
    my_module/
        __init__.py
        my_class.py
```

In `my_class.py`, you might have:

```py
# my_class.py
class MyClass:
    ...
```

And in `__init__.py`, you would include:

```py
# __init__.py
from .my_class import MyClass
```

2. **Create a `setup.py` file**: In the `my_project/` directory (the same level as `my_module/`), create a `setup.py` file:

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_module',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

3. **Install your package**: Navigate to the `my_project/` directory in your terminal and run the following command to install your package:

```bash
pip install .
```

4. **Import your class in another project**: Now you can import your class in another project like this:

```py
from my_module import MyClass
```