# Python config ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a python project and whose directory structure looks like this,

```
SEC-Edgar
├── SECEdgar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── companylist.txt
│   ├── crawler.py
│   ├── crawler.pyc
│   ├── data.txt
│   └── test.py
├── config.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

I am trying to use config module inside `crawler.py` but it is giving an `ImportError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SECEdgar/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from crawler import SecCrawler
  File "/Users/rahul/Code/SEC-Edgar/SECEdgar/crawler.py", line 9, in <module>
    from config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH
ImportError: No module named config
```

The import statement in `crawler.py` is

```
 from config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH
```

I am not able to understand how import works in python, particularly when it comes to different directories like importing from root to base directory.

Do I need to add `__init__.py` on root directory also, so that it becomes a package and then use `.` to import it?

Is there a better way to handle import or am I missing some fundamentals here?

Comment: Does `SEC-Edgar` exists in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: See if this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996391/importing-another-project-as-modules-in-python/36996510#comment61546863_36996510

Comment: Maybe try `from ../config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Comment: I think you would have to rename your `SEC-Edgar` directory to e.g. `SEC_Edgar` because module names have to follow the Python naming restrictions, which do only allow alphanumeric characters plus the underscore. This and using relative imports.

Comment: I have added `__init__.py` to SEC-Edgar and also renamed it to `secedgar` to comply with python modules name but still I am getting ImportError.

Answer (score 0):

First change the  `from config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH` to  `from ..config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH` then add an empty `__init__.py` in `SEC-Edgar` directory.

Then, try executing your module as `python -m SEC-Edgar.SECEdgar.test` or like that for any module you are running, from the location(directory) where SEC-Edgar exists.

There are three things to note here.

1. your `config.py` and `crawler.py` modules doesn't share the same parent directory. So, when you try `from config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH` from `crawler.py` Python can't import it for you.
2. We can import modules(.py files) from other directories in python only if that directory is a package. It can be done by just adding an empty `__init__.py` file in that directory.
3. We can now use relative imports. But, During relative imports Python uses the `__name__` property of the module, As per [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

> Relative imports use a module's **name** attribute to determine that
>   module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does
>   not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '**main**')
>   then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level
>   module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file
>   system.

So, we running it with `-m` option to supply the package informations for Python to perform relative imports.

[In response to comment] 
Here is what working for me,

```
SEC-Edgar
├── SECEdgar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── crawler.py
│   └── test.py
├── __init__.py
└── config.py
```

I'm outside SEC-Edgar directory,

```
C:\Users\username\Documents> ls
SEC-EDGAR  OTHERS

C:\Users\username\Documents> python -m SEC-Edgar.SECEdgar.test
Lets assume I'm an SecCrawler
```

**config.py**

```
DEFAULT_DATA_PATH = "some/path"
```

**crawler.py**

```
from ..config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH

SecCrawler = "Lets assume I'm an SecCrawler"
```

**test.py**

```
from crawler import SecCrawler

print(SecCrawler)
```

Comment: Changing from `config` to `..config` doesn't works. The only solution worked was adding project path to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yes, adding project path to PYTHONPATH will work but you have add the path when you move the project and it's not the right way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19669773/887007

Answer (score 0):

use `from ..config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH`

Refer: [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

If you get error : `Attempted relative import in non-package`

Refer : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: I get value error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package```

Comment: Create a file`__init__.py` in the parent folder.

Comment: I have created it but still I am getting the error.

Comment: Check : [packaging for relative import in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348452/python-packaging-for-relative-imports)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the issue is caused by [Python path](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

try to answer this question:
how/where can python find the module called 'config'?

So, I suggest you find these steps to understand and solve the issue:

1. reduce the scope
   in your crawler.py, use this main:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       import sys
       print(sys.path)

       from config import DEFAULT_DATA_PATH
       print 'DEFAULT_DATA_PATH=%s' % DEFAULT_DATA_PATH
   ```
2. `print(sys.path)` will show you the python path. you probally cannot find your project root in the path.
3. if you're clear that you need to manage the python path, you may config it in your IDE. e.g. I'm using pycharm, I'll [select the source root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909857/how-can-i-get-pycharm-to-find-the-right-paths-if-i-open-a-directory-that-is-not) in settings/Project Structure and check 'Add source roots to PYTHONPATH' in Run/Debug Configurations.
4. after you configured it, re-run your `crawler.py`, the output will be samilar as this:

   `['C:\\dev\\projects\\SEC-Edgar\\SECEdgar', ... 'C:\\dev\\projects\\SEC-Edgar'.]
   DEFAULT_DATA_PATH=TEST`

   `TEST` will be the value in SEC-Edgar\config.py

this is only for dev, for packaing/deployment, you'll need to config your setup.py properly. you may refer to: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html