# Getting Module Not Found error while trying to run the feature file from terminal

Tags: python, python-behave

Project Overview - My python project has a dependency on a different project which contains the driver initialization part (that project is kind of helper). I have added that project as a dependency in my current project like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDtDa.png)

in Steps for feature file i am importing some modules from dependent project. When i run the feature file from Pycharm then it's working fine. But when i run the feature file from terminal using behave command or python command then i get the "Module Not Found" error in steps file and the module that is not found is in dependant project. Can anybody assist me in resolving this. I read somewhere that we get this error when we try to run the file like script but in script importing the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding below code in my step file

from sys import path as pylib #im naming it as pylib so that we won't get confused between os.path and sys.path
import os
pylib += [os.path.abspath(r'/dependantproject path')]

u can also refer below link for explanation
[Importing another project as modules in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996391/importing-another-project-as-modules-in-python/36996510)